# Space in SQL query string from variable causing error

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am currently trying to compare dates to a value in my database set at `datetime`. It is in the format `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00`. I have a SQL String that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (start BETWEEN $from AND $to)
```

`$from` = `"2015-14-10 00:00:00"` and `$to` = `"2016-14-10 00:00:00"`

When I preform this query I get this returned to me:

`SELECT * FROM Events WHERE (start BETWEEN 2015-14-10 00:00:00 AND 2016-14-10 00:00:00) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 AND 2015-14-10 00:00:00) AND subcategory_id = 9999 LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0' at line 1`

From this I am assuming it is the space in the datetime string I created. When I put quotations around the datetime and input this into my database it queries correctly. In my query string, do I need to add quotes around the variable to make the space valid?

Comment: So add that to my string i'm setting those variables to?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried the to_date function in sql? like  (start BETWEEN to_date($from) AND to_date($to))

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed the quote ' character that must surround your constant date value.

Your previous query must be:

SELECT * FROM Events WHERE (start BETWEEN '2015-14-10 00:00:00' AND '2016-14-10 00:00:00')

Comment: I tried that and I get : `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (start BETWEEN '2015-15-10 00:00:00' AND '2016-15-10 00:00:00' LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0' at line 1`

Comment: You missed the closing parenthesis before 'limit'